# Checking of attribute of inputs not working for more than one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

There is number of select boxes and input boxes. I've written a function when the body loads. My function will check the select boxes value and send the pattern to the input. My problem is this code will repeat a pattern to all the fields e.g. If a select box was "NS" it will repeat the NS pattern to all the inputs.
Here is my snippet :

```js
$(function() {
    var value= $('select[name=type]').val();
    var pattern = $('select[name=type] option:selected').data('pattern');

    $('input[name=hostInput]').attr('pattern', pattern);
    $('input[name=hostInput]').val(value);
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS" selected data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host"/>
  <br/>
  
   <br/>
  
    <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS"  data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" selected data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host"/>
  <br/>

</form>
```

Comment: If you just want one input filled, then make each name attribute unique ex. `hostInput1`, `hostInput2`, etc.

Comment: @zer00ne  my fields come from database i can not change the name of each attribute.

Answer (score 1):

User a `$.each()` on your `input[name=hostInput]` to loop on them all.

Then use `$(this).prevAll('select[name=type]').val()` to get the previous object

```js
function run() {


  $('input.to_validate').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).prevAll('select[name=type]').val();
    var pattern = $(this).prev('select[name=type] option:selected').data('pattern');

    $(this).attr('pattern', pattern);
    $(this).val(value);
  })
}

run()

$('.minimal').change(function() {
run();
})
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS" selected data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>

  <br/>

  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host" />
  <br/>

  <br/>

  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS"  data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" selected data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>

  <br/>

  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host" />
  <br/>

  <br/>

  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS"  data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" selected data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
    
    <option value="TX" selected data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">TX </option>
  </select>

  <br/>

  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host" />
  <br/>

</form>
```

Comment: How do i change this code with classname? not name of inputbox (Hostinput)

Comment: @inaz what element shall the classname be on`? the input`?

Comment: there is another problem with your answer . when the page loads . not run the function you wrote and not pass the value and pattern to each input with class : to_validate

Comment: I changed it to select the input by class

Comment: Check again, It runs fine for me. also added an example for when you change the `select` then it updates the input value

Comment: in my question . when the body loads pattern and values of each selectbox sent to textboxes. the problem was only repeat for all . but your code does not work at all.

Comment: You problem was that it repeated the value to all checkbox? right ? what do you mean by my code dont run at all.? when i run the code in the snippet above it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to want to push the selected option to respective inputs then here you go

```js
$(function() {

$(".minimal").each(function(){
    var value= $(this).val();
    
    var pattern = $(this).find('option:selected').data('pattern');
 
    $(this).nextAll('input[name=hostInput]').eq(0).attr('pattern', pattern);
    $(this).nextAll('input[name=hostInput]').eq(0).val(value);
    
    })
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS" selected data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host"/>
  <br/>
  
   <br/>
  
    <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS"  data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" selected data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
 
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host"/>
  <br/><br/>
  
   <select name="type" class="minimal">
    <option value="Record" hidden>Record</option>
    <option value="NS" selected data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong host">NS</option>
    <option value="MX" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong Ip Placeholder">MX </option>
  </select>
  
  
  <br/>
 
  <input type="text" name="hostInput" placeholder="Hostname" class="to_validate" title="Wrong host"/>
  <br/>

</form>
```

Comment: No,i want to pass each value and pattern to each textbox when the body loads.

Comment: @inaz : Check it now

Comment: @inaz : Is this what you want. Please check the answer update